# Spring Security XML Configuration Login Issue

Tags: spring-security, authentication

I'm trying to integrate spring-security 3.1.4 in existing very old spring 3 application. I'm sure that the compatibility is good. The login is not working after the integration. Following is the security configuration.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/*.html" access="hasRole('CMS')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/UserCheck.html" authentication-failure-url="/login.html?sl=f" 
                always-use-default-target="true" login-processing-url="/login.html" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/logoutAction.html" />
    <anonymous />
</http>

<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="gov.fd.ecms.security.FDCMSUserDetailsService" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

This is a simple configuration. When ever i hit a protected url in the browser it is redirecting to login page but then it is automatically redirecting to authentication-failure-url. Browser is displaying the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I noticed that the login.html is giving the response 302 with the response header Location = /login.html?sl=f

Can some one please help to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

The login-page url and login-processing-url cannot be same. I thought the GET url for login page display and POST url for submit would work. Spring 3.1 doesn't support it, but the latest versions of spring support.